# Call two actions from Html.BeginForm ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So the first action would be:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`

and the second would be a ajax call:

`<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="deleteImages()" class="btn btn-default" />`

Ajax:

```
<script>
    let deletedImages = [];
    function Remove(id, e) {
        deletedImages.push(id);
        console.log(deletedImages);
        $(e).fadeOut(1000);
        $(e).next().fadeOut(1000);
    }

//starts here

    function deleteImages() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("DeleteImages", "Image")",
        data: { "deletedImages": deletedImages },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("deleted");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Only the `onClick` function is getting called, whereas the `Post/Edit` of the `Html.BeginForm` is not.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `onsubmit`. run onsubmit before post

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new
{ onsubmit="deleteImages()", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

second option: (using jquery)

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   deleteImages();
   return true;
});
```

Comment: I had removed a label for validation and it wasn't submitting......thanks for the reply though

Comment: I'm running into a problem, that the function gets called even if the form isn't valid.

Comment: @EL02 you can check with `$('form').valid()`

Answer (score 0):

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Post", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Maybe you are missing Area?

Something like

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Post", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))